# Data Repeater Control in winforms

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I am binding data in data repeater but i also want to bind control visibility data in binding time. how can i do it.

```
DataTable dtCourse = new DataTable();
dtCourse.Columns.Add("Course_ID");
dtCourse.Columns.Add("Visibility");
dt.Rows.Add("1","True");
dt.Rows.Add("2","False");
dt.Rows.Add("3","True");
lbl_CourseName.DataBindings.Add("Text", dtCourse, "Course_ID");
btnViewExam.DataBindings.Add("Visible", dtCourse, "Visibility");
dr_Course.DataSource = dtCourse;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code works just fine. Only rename `dt` to `dtCourse`:

```
DataTable dtCourse = new DataTable();
dtCourse.Columns.Add("Course_ID");
dtCourse.Columns.Add("Visibility");
dtCourse.Rows.Add("1", "True"); // here
dtCourse.Rows.Add("2", "False"); // here
dtCourse.Rows.Add("3", "True"); // here
lbl_CourseName.DataBindings.Add("Text", dtCourse, "Course_ID");
btnViewExam.DataBindings.Add("Visible", dtCourse, "Visibility");
dr_Course.DataSource = dtCourse;
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: but on view button click how can i get label value.

Comment: @user1939371 bind tag of button to course id, then just use that tag in click handler

Comment: if i am binding tag then button visible can not bind.

Comment: @user1939371 you can bind any number of properties at same time